# Optimal way to sort a list by reversing sublists

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, reverse

Now I recently saw this question (can't exactly remember where) about how few operations were needed to sort a list of numbers by exclusively reversing sublists.

Here is an example:
**Unsorted Input**: `3, 1, 2, 5, 4`

One of the possible answers is:
1. Reverse index 0 through 3, giving `5, 2, 1, 3, 4`
2. Reverse index 0 through 4, giving `4, 3, 1, 2, 5`
3. Reverse index 0 through 3, giving `2, 1, 3, 4, 5`
4. Reverse index 0 through 1, giving `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

However, after trying my hand at this problem it proved quite difficult for someone not experienced in algorithms to actually create a piece of code that finds the best solution. The answer noted above was simply done by brute-forcing all possible combinations, but this becomes unbearably slow when lists are longer than 10 numbers (10 takes <2s, 14 took more than 10 minutes). Refitting any existing sorting algorithms doesn't work either because they were built to only swap single elements at a time (and swapping 2 numbers by reversing sublists will take 1-2 operations which is not optimal at all). I have also tried sorting networks because the max size is already determined before running the program, but I didn't have much luck with them either (they also rely on swapping, which is inefficient when you have the ability to swap multiple at a time). I also tried to make a function that would "optimize" a list of operations, as an attempt to make existing sorting algorithms viable, but those answers were also far longer than the optimal ones (think of 16 vs 6).

So, after spending quite some time on this, I simply cannot find a better way to find the shortest solution short of brute-forcing it. As I am a student, I do not have much experience in the art of sorting, algorithms and other math "magic", but I was wondering if anyone here might have a try. The best answer of course is simply giving a hint, because I wouldn't mind trying to solve it with some hints of the smarter minds floating around StackOverflow.

Lets say that all numbers are unique and in the range 0 - 100 (both exclusive). The length of the array is something like `3 < N < 15`, because I seem to recall that the original question does not use big arrays either.

Comment: Unless I am missing something (if the starting index of the sublist can be bigger than 0) the smallest reversable sublist is a list of two which comes down to switching position.  You can pretty much apply any algorithm with this.

Comment: @ForguesR Thats true but as noted in my post that gives quite inefficient results (18 where only 6 are needed). The whole point of the question is to find the _shortest_ way to sort them.

Comment: Your use of the word "rotate" here is confusing. I think where you're using "Rotate," you mean "Reverse." Please edit your question to correct that.

Comment: To place any element into the correct spot requires only two operations. Flip it to the front of the list and then flip it into it's correct spot. For an array of n elements that gives a maximum number of 2 * n. Then you can subtract 2 from that because the last 2 elements are being placed together. This won't necessarily give an optimal solution, but it is a place to start.

Comment: @Jim Mischel I seem to confuse those a lot. Fixed now

Comment: You need to define a cost model, the cost for a _reverse_ to try and minimise total cost. (`3,1,2, 5,4`→`2,1, 3, 5,4`→`1,2, 3, 5,4`→`1,2, 3, 4,5` - for a total of 7 elements in reverses - or 6, if you don't count _middle elements_) Hint: using an algorithm renowned for low number of swaps and swap(a, b) === rev(a, b);rev(a+1, b-1) establishes an upper bound.

Comment: This seems similar to [Pancake sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting), though that assumes flipping prefixes of the list, rather than arbitrary sublists.

Comment: I think you're thinking of [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)

Comment: "A. Caprara, [Sorting by reversals is difficult](https://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~asharp/cs365/papers/C97.pdf), in Proceedings of the First International Conference on Computational Molecular Biology, ACM Press, New York, 1997, pp. 75–83." - NP-hard. "P. Berman and M. Karpinski, [On some tighter inapproximability results](http://theory.cs.uni-bonn.de/ftp/reports/cs-reports/1998/85199-CS.ps.gz) (extended abstract), in Automata, Languages and Programming (Prague, 1999), Springer, Berlin, 1999, pp. 200– 209" - MAX-SNP-hard.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing optimal but an idea to use in some similar cases.

An idea would be using recursion and keeping the "best" score encountered previously in order to avoid exploring further useless combinations.

A first limit is obviously n-1 for a list of length n: no "path" should be longer than n-1 since a trivial solution exist with score n-1.

Then let a sorting function call itself several times with parameters being:

- current state of the list
- length of the path to the current state (1, then 2, then 3, ...)
- some list of tuples being a description of the path to the current state
- best score found (initially n-1)
- description of the best solution found (list)

Each time the function is called (by itself) it can perform about n² operations and call itself again by adding 1 to the length of the path (and of course fixing other parameters as well) *but only if this incremented length remains lower than the best score*.

Since using recursion will be more or less similar to exploring a tree, you will avoid exploring some branches *if you are lucky enough to find "good" solutions soon enough*.

It should work for sizes `3 < N < 15` but you can surely find better.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution with a smaller number of swaps for your example:

1. reverse indexes 0 to 2: 2 1 3 5 4
2. reverse indexes 0 and 1: 1 2 3 5 4
3. reverse indexes 3 and 4: 1 2 3 4 5

Seems like what @greybeard suggested is the best approach. Maybe even think of a sort of heuristics based on greedy+optimization functions based on some notion of "cost".

Maybe for example for each element you can calculate "how far" it is from its original index in a sorted list and start by reversing the highest cost list first (as to minimize subsequent swaps, hopefully) until everything is sorted.

Of course, haven't really tested it, but, as a start, it might help you.

Best,
Bruno

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea that use a greedy approach (not proven to be optimal). The idea is in each step look for the reversion that maximally increases the *order*. Let's define the order of a list as the length of the longest ordered parts in that list, and let's say that a part of the list is ordered if it is sorted either forwards or backwards.

E.g. the list `[3 4 5 1 2]` has two ordered parts: `[3 4 5]` and `[1 2]`. The best move from this state would take the first 4 elements an revert them. The result is the list `[1 5 4 3 2]`. The order of the new list is increased because now the maximal ordered subsequence is 4 elements long (it it the subsequence `[5 4 3 2]`).

If no moves that increase the order of the list are is possible, then prefer a move that sorts (a part of) the list in the right order. (Also use this for breaking ties.)

On the example above this strategy works like this:

`[3 1 2 5 4]` (order 2) -> `[3 4 5 2 1]` (order 3) -> `[5 4 3 2 1]` (order 5) -> `[1 2 3 4 5]` (order 5, sorted properly).

which leads to the result in shorter time than the OP's sequence of moves. The complexity of this algorithm is `O(n^3)` or better, as each step requires comparing all `O(n^2)` possible moves.

The point where this breaks down is when there are multiple moves that give the same order. For example, if "6" is added to the end of the original example, there is a move that leads to order 4 trough the sequence `[4 5 6]`, but that move is a suboptimal choice. A possible idea how to fix this is to do not consider elements that are in their already-sorted places on both ends of the list when calculating the score. It's clear that there's never a reason to touch those elements, so the algorithm should only consider the middle, yet-unsorted part of the list.

Answer (score -1):

My intuitive feeling is that the problem can be reduced to:

1. Regard 2-tuple swaps between array neighbours, based upon their cardinality. This would be an upper bound for the number of subset reverses.
2. Compound these 2-tuple swaps to higher order (3-tuple, 4-tuple etc), reducing the number or reverses further, until no further compounding is possible.

**Regarding 1)**, I have tested this using the following java code and the supplied array [3, 1, 2, 5, 4]:

```
private static int[] reverseSort(int[] array) {
        int temp;
        int count = 0;
        boolean reversed = false;
        do {
            reversed = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
                if (array[i] > array[i+1]) {
                    temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[i+1];
                    array[i+1] = temp;
                    count++;
                    System.out.println(count + ": reverse [" + i + ", " + (i + 1) + "]");
                    reversed = true;
                }
            }
        } while (reversed);
        return array;
    }
```

This yields the following (instantaneous) output:

```
1: reverse [0, 1]
2: reverse [1, 2]
3: reverse [3, 4]
```

Already we have a simpler solution, involving only 2-tuples! (Check it).

**Regarding 2)**, I'll leave it to someone else to figure out the compounding in the general case. I'm soo tired, I want to go to bed...

**A hint** (which is what was asked for) regarding compounding: for 3-tuples, run through every consecutive set of 3 2-tuples to see if they compound to 3-tuple. So for example the switches [1,2] [2,3] [1,2] and [2,3] [1,2] [2,3] will both generate [1, 2, 3] from [3, 2, 1], and can be substituted by a compound reverse. Generalise to n-tuple, and stop when n = length of array.

Comment: (Try `break;` instead of `reversed = true;` (and using `reversed` at all) - place a comment in proximity to "the `if`-condition" as you see fit.)

Comment: We need to traverse the full array every loop, this is what determines if we have reached the end (full cardinality). Break will disrupt this.

Comment: Bubblesort with a sub-optimal condition for the inner loop? ` reducing the number or reverses` - [B. Alfred](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2535434/) still didn't present a cost model. While I'm not positive about _compounding 'neighbour-swaps'_, I'm with you re. fatigue.